# Apache mod_rewrite does not work although loaded

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

My application worked with .htaccess when it was on localhost

When I uploaded the application to the server, the .htaccess is not working.

Through phpinfo(); I noticed that mod_rewrite is loaded under apache2handler.

I suspect my .htaccess rule maybe wrong, so I tested with

http://www.webune.com/forums/viewtopic-p-62.html

but it still didnt work, the 404 page is showed.

What should be the valid reasons for above problem?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set to None or something that is preventing you from controlling mod_rewrite within an .htaccess file. You're going to need to be able to modify Apache's config to change that.

Comment: I dont have the control over Apache's config, guess that I will have to stick with the ugly URL :(

Comment: Just type something invalid (e.g. `InvalidProperty On`) into your htaccess and see if you get a 500 internal server error page. If not than htaccess is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you test it: [How To Check If mod_rewrite is Enabled in Apache](http://www.wallpaperama.com/disp-post19.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your Apache config files, look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/htaccess.html.

Check the AccessFileName parameter if it is .htaccess. It should be by default. If it is, then it is a problem with the site configuration. Refer to Jonathan's answer for that solution.